# Looping through unique json formatted data in Handlebars JS

Tags: jquery, json, html, iteration, handlebars.js

I ran into a problem attempting to loop through my JSON object. What I attempted made plenty sense and would like to know why it is not working.

here is the last attempt I made to make this work.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="partnerTemplate">
    {{#each partners}}
    <div>{{this.Name}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Here is the object I'm trying to pull data from.

```
partners = renderer({
    Cerner: {
        Name: 'Cerner',
        Selected: false
    },
    Walmart: {
        Name: 'Walmart',
        Selected: false
    }
});
```

Pretty much what I want to do is select the name of the current object the #each is iterating through. So I would think this.Name would return two values (Cerner, Walmart).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my problem was based on how my data was structured. I'm still not sure why "this.Name" didn't work but I figured out a way around it. Instead of using base objects for everything I changed my data to be an array of objects.

```
   data = renderer({
        partners: [
            {
                Name: 'Cerner',
                Selected: false
            },
            {
                Name: 'Walmart',
                Selected: false
            }
        ]
    });
```

and the html or handbars.js

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="partnerTemplate">
        {{#each partners}}
        <div>{{Name}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```